# Custom Error in Active Record Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, custom-errors

I am using HMVC. My question is very simple. how we can catch the error in active records?
how we can return custom error to controller from model(active records)?

Actually, msn column is unique so, when i enter duplicate value then its show error like

Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry '3696003284' for key 'msn'

but i want to show custom error instead of this.

my simple code is:

```
function insert_data($msn_number, $date_val, $min_val, $max_val, $avg_val,$counter)
{
    for($i=0;$i<$counter;$i++)
    {
        $data = array(
            'msn'     => $msn_number[$i],
            'date'    => $date_val[$i],
            'min_val' => $min_val[$i],
            'max_val' => $max_val[$i],
            'average' => $avg_val[$i]
        );
        $result = $this->db->insert('storage_data', $data);
        if(!isset($result))
         {
           echo "custom Error";
          }

    }
 }
```

}

i am wondering for the answer of this question please help me!

Comment: i don't know how i catch this error?

Comment: any idea, can i check for already existence of 'msn' within query if exist then update that row otherwise insert new row?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$result = $this->db->insert('storage_data', $data);
if (!$result) {
    $data['msg'] = $this->db->_error_message();
    $this->load->view('viw_db_error', $data); // Create a viw_db_error.php view
}
```

Make sure `DB_DEBUG` is set to `FALSE` in the `application/config/database.php` file, or execution will be halted if a `mysql` error occurs.

**Update:**

Alternatively you may query for that before every time you insert a new record but it would be very expensive because you are doing it inside a loop and it'll send many query/requests:

```
$q = $this->db->query("select msn from storage_data where msn = $msn_number[$i]");
if( $q->num_rows() ) {
    // It already exists so maybe display a message
}
```

Comment: Thanks WEREWOLF for reply but, Actually i need any other way without making DB_DEBUG FALSE?

Comment: Thanks for attention! but in this way query will run 100 of times so, i think it will make system very slow!